# Does Java have native OS file system events monitoring support?

Tags: java

Is filesystem polling only option? Or is there support for `FSEvents` (OSX), `ReadDirectoryChangesW` (Windows)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [a `WatchService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html):

> The implementation that observes events from the file system is intended to map directly on to the native file event notification facility where available, or to use a primitive mechanism, such as polling, when a native facility is not available

You can also have a look at this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) which confirms that point

> Most file system implementations have native support for file change notification. The Watch Service API takes advantage of this support where available. However, when a file system does not support this mechanism, the Watch Service will poll the file system, waiting for events

Comment: Any way to check if the native OS APIs are really used? If I run that example and modify a file in a folder that's being watched it takes about 4-5 seconds to detect the change whereas with a C program using FSEvents it detects the change instantly.

Comment: I don't know to be honest... You may find more info in that thread: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nio-dev/2014-August/002691.html (and the answer seems to be that it uses polling in OSX)

Comment: Ok, so no native support for OSX yet in the JDK/JRE.

Comment: 2020 can confirm. still lacking for osx

Answer (score 0):

[WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) is meant to provide this functionality, and there are implementations that use native events included in the JRE for most major OSes except for macOS (as of Feb. 2020).

For macOS, [gmethvin/directory-watcher](https://github.com/gmethvin/directory-watcher) includes an open source [implementation of WatchService](https://github.com/gmethvin/directory-watcher/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/methvin/watchservice/MacOSXListeningWatchService.java) that uses native events that can be used.